# Узнать количество измененных/добавленных записей

Tags: mysql

Как в самом mySQL узнать количество измененных/добавленных записей операторами UPDATE,INSERT? Нужен php-аналог $mysqli->affected_rows для mySQL, чтобы вернуть как значение в хранимой процедуре.

ROW_COUNT() всегда возвращает нуль:

```
UPDATE temp SET str='dsv235fgfg4';
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

Comment: *ROW_COUNT() всегда возвращает нуль:* https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9303fd62400dd155fab6ca4f95398894

Comment: Проверял это в HeidiSQL, возвращает нуль. Возможно между двумя этими операторами клиент еще какие-то скрытые действия производит. Обернул этот код в хранимую процедуру и вернул RETURN-ом. Работает как надо.

Comment: *Возможно между двумя этими операторами клиент еще какие-то скрытые действия производит.* В окне лога отображаются все выполняемые запросы. См. там.